# Update Files using Linux command line

Tags: linux, command-line

I'm trying to create an update script that will merge the contents of two directories. I have a master directory that has a structure like:

```
master
 - dir1
    - subdir1
    - subdir2
 - dir2
 - dir3
```

and an update directory like

```
update
  - dir1
    -subdir2
```

How do I create a script that iterates through the update directory and replaces content in the master. I since the contents of the update directories contain different files than the master, it is imperative that I do not MERGE the files but replace the entire subdirectory.

I've tried this

```
for D in $(find -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type d) ; 
do
    rm -rf .$D
done
```

to remove the master directories but can't figure out how to manipulate the $D variable to copy the contents of the update to the master. Perhaps this isn't the best way but couldn't find any other alternatives.

Comment: Does subdir2 under update contain the entire master-tree, or just the same subdir2 that is present in master?

Comment: subdir just contains a set of files, no additional subdirectories

Answer (score 0):

I finally did this:

```
for D in $(find -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type d) ; 
do

  rm -rf ../${D:2}
  cp -avr ${D:2}/ ../${D:2}

done
```